# Compile time check or java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, loops, concurrency, concurrentmodification

The loop below throws `ConcurrentModificationException`. Should it have given compiler error instead. What is the reason to go for Runtime Exception?

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("AAAAAAAAAAAAA");
for (final String it : list) {
    System.out.println(it);
    list.add("SSSSSSSSSS");
}
```

Comment: Why would it ever throw a compile error? You are making a valid method call to a declared object instance. It's not the compilers job to determine the *contextual* validity of the call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some implementations of `List` may allow a call to `add` while being iterated via an `Iterator`. For example, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` would not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Why a `RuntimeException`? Because it is the programmer's job to know whether or not that specific implementation of `List` being used would allow that behavior. For what it is worth, there are static code analyzers like FindBugs which can warn you against dangerous patterns like that.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because you're trying to modify the list while you iterate over it. It can be avoid iterating over its iterator with a normal for or a while.